# to adjust the voice level of mediaplayer in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to adjust the voice level of mediaplayer from my form with a different component but I couldn't find any options for this.
Do you know how I to do this ?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Fast googling gives multiple results involving `mciSendCommand` function.
Try this solution http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/mediaplayer_vol.htm